# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

when trying to run the following code, both with `bindValue` and `bindParam` yet can't seem to see what is wrong.

```
class Product {

    public function productAdd($x) {
        $core = Core::getInstance(); // This part works OK
        $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name) VALUES (:product-name)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':product-name', $x, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}

$product = new Product;
$productadd = $product->productAdd('Blue Sunglasses');
```

Comment: I wonder if it's because of the `-`.  Try without that, like `:productName`

Comment: OMG ? Duh, yup, that did it. Thanks!!! Can't believe that. It took me hours!!! Fresh eyes are always welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

named parameters must be one of these:

```
BINDCHR     = [:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
```

change the hyphen to an underscore or remove it.